# how to remove 'ing' from any word

Tags: python, string, input, slice, cpu-word

I need to remove *ing* from the ends of words that have *ing* in them. If a word doesn't have *ing* in it, then don't do anything and print that.

I've tried some code using `input` and word - ing but they don't work.

```
wrd = input("Word: ")
print(wrd - "ing")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have words like springing or singing, use `re`:

```
import re
wrd = input("Word: ")
print(re.sub("ing$", "", wrd))
```

Comment: Want to try that with the word "winning"?

Comment: You should remove the `rstrip` part of your answer. It's wrong.

Comment: @U10-Forward: remove the first solution, it's wrong for any word containing "i" or "n" or "g", and they are not absurd corner cases.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It's been removed!

Answer (score 6):

Heres another method:

```
>>> wrd = input("Word: ")
Word: wording
>>> print(wrd[:-3] if wrd[-3:] == "ing" else wrd)
'word'
>>>
```

This only deletes the `ing` at the end of the string.

*Raw Code:*

```
print(wrd[:-3] if wrd[-3:] == "ing" else wrd)
```

---

Heres some time taken test:

```
import timeit
import re

wrd = "counting timeing"

def method1():
    re.sub("ing$", "", wrd)

def method2():
    wrd[:-3] if wrd.endswith('ing') else wrd

def method3():
    wrd[:-3] if wrd[-3:] == "ing" else wrd

print(timeit.timeit(method1))
print(timeit.timeit(method2))
print(timeit.timeit(method3))
```

Output for me is:

> 2.3050724
>   0.3981412
>   0.37868440000000003

So the method 3, which I have answered is the fastest

Comment: Have you tested with other string?

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon I have passed it through rough tests. Works perfectly

Comment: I know your method works, I just doubt your assertion `So the method 3, which I have answered is the fastest`

Comment: Why @ComplicatedPhenomenon

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon You can perform the tests. It might be different for you but its always the fastest for me

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Most likely you're testing it the wrong way

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon My test gave 

6.688556291999703
1.11655900599726
1.1157615970005281

However Black Thunder's solution is still faster by a bit, let's end it by saying that you two are very close on timing

Comment: @U10-Forward Great.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon "I just doubt your assertion" that means you're saying you always win, how is that?

Comment: @U10-Forward I mean you can't make an assertion like that with only one specific test.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon I tested it several times on my platform. My method always wins.. What made you think I tested once only?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(x[:-3] if x.endswith('ing') else x )
```